# Wordpress Mediafiles are no longer displayed after changing the upload directory

Tags: php, wordpress

After I changed the upload directory in wp-config.php via `define( 'UPLOADS', 'files' );` no uploaded files are shown in the media overview anymore.

I also noticed how the file url has changed in the process

Before:http://xxx.xx/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/image_test.png

After:
http://xxx.xx/wp-content/uploads//mnt/web317/e2/92/535492/htdocs/XXXXXX/files/2021/07/image_test-1.png

However, I get a "page not found" message when I enter the URL directly in the browser and apart from that the URL is not correct either.
But the files are placed in the correct folder (in the web site root under ./files).

Where could possible sources of error lie here?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem using a plugin I found called "WP Original Media Path", with it everything worked without problems.